# I need to combine multiple dataframes into one large dataframe as panel data

Tags: r, panel-data

So I used this code in order to import my csv files all at once. What I need now is to create one big dataframe that is essentially panel data.

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.delim)
```

For each file I have a time variable from 1901 to 2021, a variable which takes the name of the country (e.g Argentina) and other variables which are subnational units that I do not care for and I don't need them. Each country has a different number of subnational units with different names, but again, I don't need them. I just need the time variable and the country variable which is essentially mean temperature.

When I import each csv, they look like this:

[image]

I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks.

Comment: There are 2 options.  Either using `do.call( mayflies, rbind)` or `dplyr::bind_rows()`. See help for more information

Comment: I think you meant `do.call(rbind, myfiles)`, not the reverse @Dave2e. A third option is `data.table::rbindlist(myfiles)`.

Comment: `read.delim` expects tab-delimited by default. Your data is comma separated, so try `read.csv`.